# JQuery map highlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-highlightfade

I am need paint my image. I'm trying use JQuery in here this link: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

When I am using mouseover does work, but I need when open page all images are painted without mouseover ?

how to do this ?

thanks.

Comment: did u try $('img[usemap]').maphilight()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('.targetClass').mouseover();
}
```

Here you have demo doing almost exactly what you are asking for:
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

I still haven't success, see: http://189.112.114.45:8080/ResidencialThobiasLandim
The image paint works with mouseover, but I'm needing when page is opened.

thanks again.

Comment: Haha, that's good! As they say - RTFM ;) But as an exercise we should try how to achieve the same without this option ;)